# MailDev with Symfony 5 Mailer TLS crash

Tags: symfony, email, ssl, crash

I'm working on my local machine on a Symfony 5 project. To test some mail functionality, I decided to use Node.js MailDev package.

The problem is that I found that MailDev does not support TLS encryption at this moment (version 1.1.0), and I found nothing on Symfony Mailer configuration that's allowed me to disable mail encryption.

When I try to send an email with encryption, MailDev server just crashes.

How can I solve that?

Thanks,
Navalex

Answer (score 5):

Please try:

1. In .env file: `MAILER_DSN=smtp://localhost:1025`
2. Start server: `maildev --hide-extensions STARTTLS`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using docker try this command

```
docker run -p 1080:80 -p 1025:25 nameofyourcontainer --web 80 --smtp 25 --hide-extensions STARTTLS
```